# My package.json bundleDependencies are automatically installing to latest version inside docker image

Tags: docker, npm, kubernetes, dockerfile

When I am running "npm install" inside my Dockerfile. Then all of my bundleDependencies  are automatically installing to their latest version instead of their listed version in devDependencies.

Comment: It is a good practice to add some configuration files to your question to let people see what can be wrong

Comment: npm creates a `package-lock.json` file that specifies the exact versions installed. If `package-lock.json` is present when you run `npm install` it should install the same versions.